# Bootstrap 3: Table inside a <div class="well">, but rendered outside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 in a layout of an e-Commerce website. It happens that I put a

```
<table class="table">
```

inside a

```
<div class="well">
```

in my code, but it renders out of the well, according to this image.[image]

Has someone here faced this problem? I looked Bootstrap 3 documentation, but there is not even a clue about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your items inside a **div** and assign **clearfix** class to it.

Comment: Not yet. But I'll do it right now. Should I add this class to the table or to the div?

Comment: You can try wrapping your items inside a div and assign .clearfix to it.Tell me if it works.

Comment: .clearfix applied to the div solved the problem. Thank you @Jesus! (This sounded really religious!)

Comment: Thank for valorate my answer @EdvaldoAlmeidaJr. :) This problems is common.

Comment: I haven't faced this problem before and you saved my day, buddy! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove/change the css of the table: "table-layout: fixed;"

```html
<table class="table" style="table-layout: unset">
```